# Call data from Nodej.s into react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to call an API(which only allows server side calls) in nodejs. I manage to get the info back to my console, and now Im trying to pass that data to the app.js file of my react app.

Im currently working with a react app a node.js back end and express to communicate between them.

I have two folder `backend` and `client`

This is `backend/server.js`:

```
const express = require('express')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Set up the express app
const app = express();
const API_PORT = 3001;
// Parse incoming requests data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
  });

app.get("/bitmex", () => !async function(){
      const api = new BitmexAPI({
       "apiKeyID": "-",
       "apiKeySecret": ""
 });
   const chatMessage = await atMessage.json({ success: true, chatMessage})
}())

 app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

This is Client/Appjs

```
    // /client/App.js
    import React, { Component } from "react";


    class App extends Component {
      // initialize our state 
      state = {
        data: [],
        id: 0,
        message: null,
        intervalIsSet: false,
        idToDelete: null,
        idToUpdate: null,
        objectToUpdate: null
      };



      // when component mounts, first thing it does is fetch all existing data in our db
      // then we incorporate a polling logic so that we can easily see if our db has 
      // changed and implement those changes into our UI
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log("yes")
        console.log(this.getDataFromDb());
      }


      getDataFromDb = () => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitmex")
          .then(data => data.json())
          .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
      };




      // here is our UI
      // it is easy to understand their functions when you 
      // see them render into our screen
      render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>{Object.keys(this.state.data[0]).map((key) => { return <li>{key}</li> })}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

The response from the API looks like this:

> ```
> [
>    {
>     "account": 0,
>     "symbol": "string",
>     "currency": "string",
>     "underlying": "string",
>     "quoteCurrency": "string",
>     "commission": 0,
>     "initMarginReq": 0,
>     "maintMarginReq": 0,
>     "riskLimit": 0,
>     "leverage": 0,
>     "crossMargin": true,
>     "deleveragePercentile": 0,
>     "rebalancedPnl": 0,
>     "prevRealisedPnl": 0,
>     "prevUnrealisedPnl": 0,
>     "prevClosePrice": 0,
>     "openingTimestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.780Z",
>     "openingQty": 0,
>     "openingCost": 0,
>     "openingComm": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyQty": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyCost": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyPremium": 0,
>     "openOrderSellQty": 0,
>     "openOrderSellCost": 0,
>     "openOrderSellPremium": 0,
>     "execBuyQty": 0,
>     "execBuyCost": 0,
>     "execSellQty": 0,
>     "execSellCost": 0,
>     "execQty": 0,
>     "execCost": 0,
>     "execComm": 0,
>     "currentTimestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.780Z",
>     "currentQty": 0,
>     "currentCost": 0,
>     "currentComm": 0,
>     "realisedCost": 0,
>     "unrealisedCost": 0,
>     "grossOpenCost": 0,
>     "grossOpenPremium": 0,
>     "grossExecCost": 0,
>     "isOpen": true,
>     "markPrice": 0,
>     "markValue": 0,
>     "riskValue": 0,
>     "homeNotional": 0,
>     "foreignNotional": 0,
>     "posState": "string",
>     "posCost": 0,
>     "posCost2": 0,
>     "posCross": 0,
>     "posInit": 0,
>     "posComm": 0,
>     "posLoss": 0,
>     "posMargin": 0,
>     "posMaint": 0,
>     "posAllowance": 0,
>     "taxableMargin": 0,
>     "initMargin": 0,
>     "maintMargin": 0,
>     "sessionMargin": 0,
>     "targetExcessMargin": 0,
>     "varMargin": 0,
>     "realisedGrossPnl": 0,
>     "realisedTax": 0,
>     "realisedPnl": 0,
>     "unrealisedGrossPnl": 0,
>     "longBankrupt": 0,
>     "shortBankrupt": 0,
>     "taxBase": 0,
>     "indicativeTaxRate": 0,
>     "indicativeTax": 0,
>     "unrealisedTax": 0,
>     "unrealisedPnl": 0,
>     "unrealisedPnlPcnt": 0,
>     "unrealisedRoePcnt": 0,
>     "simpleQty": 0,
>     "simpleCost": 0,
>     "simpleValue": 0,
>     "simplePnl": 0,
>     "simplePnlPcnt": 0,
>     "avgCostPrice": 0,
>     "avgEntryPrice": 0,
>     "breakEvenPrice": 0,
>     "marginCallPrice": 0,
>     "liquidationPrice": 0,
>     "bankruptPrice": 0,
>     "timestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.781Z",
>     "lastPrice": 0,
>     "lastValue": 0
>   }
> ]
> ```

I m looking to get the info returned by the API into the client side, no need to render just want to be able to have it I can figure out rendering

Comment: You're already calling getDataFromDb and setting the data to state so what is your question?

Comment: Well Im able to call from nodejs, but when I try to pull that data in the front end Im not able I get 404, Im 90% sure the back end is right I just need help refactoring the front end to be able to at least `console.log` the info pulled. Because right now its not working.

Comment: Can you call http://localhost:3001/bitmex outwith the react app? E.g. with postman? What port is react app running on?

Comment: react is running on 3000, the server is running on 3001 and now that you mention it, no I can not

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/bitmex", () => !async function(){
  const api = new BitmexAPI({
    "apiKeyID": "-",
    "apiKeySecret": ""
  });
  const chatMessage = await atMessage.json({ success: true, chatMessage})
}())
```

This should probably be:

```
app.get("/bitmex", async (req, res) => {
  const api = new BitmexAPI({
    "apiKeyID": "-",
    "apiKeySecret": ""
  });
  const chatMessage = await atMessage.json({ success: true, chatMessage})

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  res.end(chatMessage)
})
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem. But a `404` from your client app means that your API endpoint probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you still get a 404 from your client app ?

Comment: By the way, it probably should be `.then(res => this.setState({ data: res[0] }));` and not `.then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));` since the data your API returns is an array

Comment: I deleted the db since I've decided I do not need to save data, just need to stream it through the app. Currently Im getting `Cannot GET /btimex`

Comment: Try to type `http://localhost:3001/bitmex` into your browser URL bar. If that still returns you a `404`, it's definitely a server problem.

Comment: Does not vene load that page, so its definitely a server error, how can I structure this so it works then?

Comment: Maybe try to send a simple thing like a hello world through your endpoint: `app.get('/bitmex', (req, res) => { res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); res.end('Hello'); });` to see if you can access your endpoint. If that's not the case, maybe troubleshoot `BitmexAPI`